Why is the compiler telling me I have used a label that is not defined
Consider this C code
char str[] = "this is a string!";
    int titlecase(char* c) {
      int words = 0;
      int last_was_whitespace = 1;
      while (*c) {
        if (last_was_whitespace && *c >= ’a’ && *c <= ’z’) {
          *c ^= 32;
          last_was_whitespace = 0;
        } else {
          if (*c == ’ ’) {
            words += 1 - last_was_whitespace;
            last_was_whitespace = 1;
          } else {
            last_was_whitespace = 0;
          }
        }
        c++;
      }
      return words + 1 - last_was_whitespace;
    }
    int main() {
      int words = titlecase(str);
      puts(str);

}

I need to tranlate this into RISC-V Assembler and not used Pseudo Instrusctions (except for ecall and la). This is my attempt
    .data
    str: .string "this  is a  string!"
 
.globl main

.text 

titlecase: 
    addi sp,sp,-16
    sw ra,12(sp) # return adress
    sw a0,8(sp) # *c
    addi s0,s0,0 # int words
    addi s1,s1,1 # int last_was_whitespace
    lw s2,'a' 
    lw s3,'z'
    lw s4,' '
    addi s5,zero,1 # s5 = 1

while:
    lw t0,0(a0) # *c
    and t1,s1,t0 # last_was_whitespace && *c 
    bne t0,zero, end_while # while condition
        blt t1, s2, L1 # (last_was_whitespace && *c >= ’a’)
        L1: bge t0,s3,L2 #  (*c <= ’z’)
        # if(last_was_whitespace && *c >= ’a’ && *c <= ’z’) was not met; else
        bne t0,t4,L4
            sub t3,s5,s1 ## 1-last_was_whitespace
            add s0,s0,t3 ## words = words + last_was_whitespace
            addi s1,zero,1 ## last_was_whitespace = 1
            addi t0,t0,1 #c++
        L4:
            addi s1,zero,0 ## last_was_whitespace = 0
        
        L2:
            xori t2,t0,32 #*c ^= 32;
            addi s1,zero,0 # last_was_whitespace = 0                     
end_while: 
    lw ra,12(sp) # return adress
    lw a0,8(sp) # *c
    addi sp,sp, 16
    add a0,s0,t3
  
    jalr zero,ra,0 #exit
    
main:
    la s0,str
    jal ra,titlecase
    add s6,zero,a0
    
    addi a0, zero, 1
    add  a1, zero, s6
    ecall

I am getting an error "label 'a' used but not defined" I cannot seem to find it since it is not pointing me at the line where the error is occuring,and I just do not see it. I have no labels that are defined as 'a' where could the error be coming from. Thanks in advance

lw s2,'a'  is wrong, you wanted li or since you are not allowed pseudo, addi s2,zero,'a'. Similarly for the next two lines.
